# Function using a loop in Rstudio

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I am creating a function, which i want to create a new column with the data of the column "num_casos"

```
suavizar = function(dataset, nombre_columna){
  for ( i in 8:nrow(dataset)){
    dataset[i, nombre_columna] = sum(dataset[(i-7):(i-1),"num_casos"])/7}
}


suavizar(casos_10_19,"casos_10_19")

#The Output:

       fecha num_casos
1   2020-03-02         8
2   2020-03-03         4
3   2020-03-04         3
4   2020-03-05        16
```

Why my function doesnt create a new column in my data frame?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the function like below

```
suavizar <- function(dataset, nombre_columna){
  for ( i in 8:nrow(dataset)){
    dataset[i, nombre_columna] <- sum(dataset[(i-7):(i-1),"num_casos"])/7}
  }
  dataset
}
```